# Spark dataframe to jackson json in scala

Tags: json, scala, jackson, jackson-databind, objectmapper

I am creating a json from spark df to send that to kafka topic using Jackson.

Below is the code.

```
val columnNameArray=df.columns
df.foreachPartition(partition=> 
   { 
val producer=new kafkaProducer[String,String](props)
partition.foreach(msg=>{
val objectMapper:ObjectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
val jsonParentNode:ObjectNode=objectMapper.createObjectNode();
val jsonNode=ObjectNode=objectMapper.createObjectNode();
jsonParentNode.putPOJO("IDNUM",idnum)
for(i<- columnNamesArray){
jsonNode.putPOJO(i,msg.getAs[String](i))
}

jsonParentNode.putPOJO("msg",jsonNode);
val strMsg=jsonParentNode.toString();

val record=new ProducerRecord[String,String]("testtopuc",strMsg)

Producer.send(record)
})
```

In the process of doing so, the dataframe with date  or timestamp datatype get converted and appear as numbers.

If date value is : 2022-04-05 and is date datatype,  it appears like...166262677880000

How can I preserve the data from such fields and have it as what is there in source df.

Comment: Have you tried if `configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)` helps, like [here](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/blob/d3b0cf760705809cd993684691c3d500e5a93512/jsoniter-scala-benchmark/shared/src/main/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter_scala/benchmark/JacksonSerDesers.scala#L48)?

Comment: Yes, I did but see no difference. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Do we need to add any dependencies and the register modules? I just added the configure part in my code and observed no difference.

Comment: To update it here,  I was creating the strMsg in the wrong way.................................. val strMsg=jsonParentNode.toString(); After using writeValueAsString instead of above , I could see the functionality of the above configuration working as expected.